# Disable Raylib Iog messages

Tags: logging, rust, raylib

Is there a way to disable the output of Raylib?
I'd like to not have this spammed in my terminal:

```
INFO: Initializing raylib 3.7
INFO: DISPLAY: Device initialized successfully
INFO:     > Display size: 1920 x 1080
INFO:     > Render size:  1024 x 768
INFO:     > Screen size:  1024 x 768
INFO:     > Viewport offsets: 0, 0
INFO: TEXTURE: [ID 1] Unloaded texture data from VRAM (GPU)
INFO: TEXTURE: [ID 2] Unloaded texture data from VRAM (GPU)
INFO: TEXTURE: [ID etc...] Unloaded texture data from VRAM (GPU)
```

There's more of these, this is just a portion of them

Comment: Hi @Oughie, Please share some more information how you are using raylib. A code snippet containing the first few method calls into raylib would be good.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which rust bindings are you using?

Answer (score 3):

**Rust Solution 1:**
You can call

```
set_trace_log(TraceLogLevel::LOG_ERROR)
```

to set a higher log level, as mentioned in the [docs here](https://docs.rs/raylib/latest/raylib/core/logging/fn.set_trace_log.html).

**C Solution 1: Set a higher log level**

```
SetTraceLogLevel(LOG_ERROR);
```

possible values are:

```
LOG_ALL: 0
LOG_TRACE: 1
LOG_DEBUG: 2
LOG_INFO: 3
LOG_WARNING: 4
LOG_ERROR: 5
LOG_FATAL: 6
LOG_NONE: 7
```

**C Solution 2: Use custom callback function**

Another way can be seen in this example [`examples/core/core_custom_logging.c`](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/examples/core/core_custom_logging.c)

you should be able to register a callback function for handling log messages

```
SetTraceLogCallback(CustomLog); // call this before InitWindow() 

InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "titel");
```

To receive no log prints whatsoever, the function can be as simple as:

```
void CustomLog(int msgType, const char *text, va_list args)
{ 
  return;
}
```

Comment: Hey @wschopohl if it helps, your answer was exactly what I was looking for with my own personal project based on the Raylib-CsLo C# bindings!

Comment: Hey, I'm glad this answer could help you! Thx!

Comment: Hey @wschopohl, for me what worked (using raylib-bindings for rust) was: ```unsafe {
        ffi::SetTraceLogLevel(ffi::TraceLogLevel::LOG_ERROR as i32);
    }``` Sorry for not responding for a long time

Comment: Hey @Oughie, if you are using the rust "raylib-rs" you should also be able to use core::logging::set_trace_log, referenced here: https://docs.rs/raylib/latest/raylib/core/logging/fn.set_trace_log.html

Comment: Hey @Oughie, if you feel generous I would be happy if you could accept my answer. It is hard enough to collect points on SO .. :)